# How to add region just above title for omega theme?

Tags: theming

How to add region just above title for omega theme? I try to add a region just above title. But no sccessful.

Comment: Can you please post the code how you tried ?

Comment: how did u try to add a region??

Answer (score 2):

In case you're using Omega 4 you need to include your regions in two files, instead of only the `.info` file.

You also need to include them in your `layout.inc` file, which is located in the theme's folder at:

> layouts/yourlayout/yourlayout.layout.inc

and then print them at the desired spot in your HTML markup in your `layout.tpl.php` file, which is in the same folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Which version of Omega do you use? In version 3 there's no layout.inc file, you add regions and their associated settings in the .info file alone

Comment: I've only worked with Omega 4. I've edited my answer so this is clear to others as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way might be to use the [Blockify module](https://drupal.org/project/blockify)